# Accessing Spotify Data API

Tags: node.js, database, api, analytics, spotify

I am trying to access the Spotify Data API and I'm struggling to find any information on this. I have managed to access the standard Web API as described on the developer.spotify site and have been able to perform simple tasks such as getting track names, album names etc.

However, the Data API is what I'm interested in. [This link](https://sites.google.com/a/spotify.com/spotify-hub/resources/analytics_data#TOC-Data-API) describes to how to access it but I cannot find anything online referring to this.

I would really appreciate some help accessing this.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: Do I need to already have access to the Spotify Analytics resource?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for access. Spotify will probably give you API documentation when they grant you access.

Comment: Is the application for the data API the form just underneath the "Data API" section on the link I posted above?

Comment: Did you read the page you are linking to? It says that the form is to access spotify analytics, and that Data API access is given by the account manager.

Comment: yeah I did. I don't know what my "local account manager" is though.  Is this someone I might work with or is it someone who works at Spotify?